# vitePreprocess in SvelteKit triggers Preprocessor dependency "sass" not found when using scss

Tags: sass, svelte, vite, sveltekit

I have a brand new project using SvelteKit. By default, `vitePreprocess` is used to handle scss and other files, as described in the [docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/integrations):

> vite-plugin-svelte offers a vitePreprocess feature which utilizes Vite
> for preprocessing. It is capable of handling the language flavors Vite
> handles: TypeScript, PostCSS, SCSS, Less, Stylus, and SugarSS. For
> convenience, it is re-exported from the @sveltejs/kit/vite package. If
> you set your project up with TypeScript it will be included by
> default:

```
// svelte.config.js
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
 
export default {
  preprocess: [vitePreprocess()]
};
```

However, if I use `lang="scss"` in my files:

```
<style lang="scss">
    ....
</style>
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Error while preprocessing /Users/francesco.leardini/Documents/pet projects/budget-tracker/src/routes/+page.svelte - Preprocessor dependency "sass" not found. Did you install it?
    at loadPreprocessor (file:///Users/francesco.leardini/Documents/pet%20projects/budget-tracker/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-5e7f419b.js:36922:19)
    at scss (file:///Users/francesco.leardini/Documents/pet%20projects/budget-tracker/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-5e7f419b.js:36962:20)
    at compileCSS (file:///Users/francesco.leardini/Documents/pet%20projects/budget-tracker/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-5e7f419b.js:36482:40)
    at async preprocessCSS (file:///Users/francesco.leardini/Documents/pet%20projects/budget-tracker/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-5e7f419b.js:36644:12)
    at async style (file:///Users/francesco.leardini/Documents/pet%20projects/budget-tracker/node_modules/@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte/dist/index.js:2055:20)
    at async process_single_tag (file:///Users/francesco.leardini/Documents/pet%20projects/budget-tracker/node_modules/svelte/compiler.mjs:46844:27)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async replace_in_code (file:///Users/francesco.leardini/Documents/pet%20projects/budget-tracker/node_modules/svelte/compiler.mjs:46732:26)
    at async process_tag (file:///Users/francesco.leardini/Documents/pet%20projects/budget-tracker/node_modules/svelte/compiler.mjs:46858:29)
    at async preprocess (file:///Users/francesco.leardini/Documents/pet%20projects/budget-tracker/node_modules/svelte/compiler.mjs:46898:30)
```

Shouldn't `scss` files be handled out of the box as stated in the docs?

Answer (score 2):

Add the dependency `sass` to your project first?

`npm add -D sass` or with whatever package manager you use.

Comment: I can try that, however by reading the docs, `vitePreprocess` should handle scss directly. Sass as an explicit dependency was needed for `svelte-preprocess` plugin, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Just add sass to the devDependencies solved the problem for me. Installing it via `npm add -D sass` or `yarn install --dev sass` hasn't worked for me. I had to manually add it to devDependencies.